# Why is it exerted a torque from the wheel on the body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I'm looking at papers about two wheeled balancing robots. But they all seem to have a torque acting from the wheel on the body. As seen in figure 7 bellow. $M_M$ is the torque in question. Even though the motor is fixed on the body, the rotor freely rotates without creating a reaction torque on the body. What is it that I'm misunderstanding?

[image]

From http://hrcak.srce.hr/file/132177

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking how the motor can create the wheel torque or whether the angular momentum of the motor itself matters?

Comment: I'm mostly asking why there is a torque $M_M$ in figure 7. The motor should not exert a torque on the body from my understanding of mechanics.

Comment: The motor stator is usually connected to the body and the rotor to the wheel (through a suitable transmission to make the torque large enough) and this causes the torque.

Comment: Isn't the job of a motor to provide $M_M$ based on the supplied current? Otherwise it would be a flywheel and not a _motor_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body includes a motor which exerts a torque on the wheel to make it turn.  The motor and wheel (or rotor) are connected via a drive chain or belt.  The wheel exerts an equal and opposite torque on the motor and thereby the body.  This is just **Newton's 3rd Law** applied to rotational forces (torques).

You say that the rotor freely rotates, but if (or when) this is true then it cannot be attached to the motor.